# Download file with c# HttpClient on raspberry pi

Tags: c#, mono, httpclient

I'm trying to download a file to a usb-disk with mono on a raspberry pi.

I'm using framework 4.5 and HttpClient class to acomplish this task, it seems everything ok, except by the CPU is growing up to 100%. this is normal? or I'm doing something wrong?, If I try download the same file with curl the CPU ran at 5% - 10% approx while download the file.

this is my code sample:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace StreamSpeedTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Sample video File
            const string fileUrl = "http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi";
            // SaveTo location
            const string file = "/tmp/big_buck_bunny.avi";

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start ...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            var buffer = new byte[80 * 1024];

            var client=new HttpClient();
            var response = client.GetAsync(fileUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stream = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

                var finfo = new FileInfo(file);

                if (finfo.Directory == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong file path!");
                    return;
                }

                if (!finfo.Directory.Exists) finfo.Directory.Create();

                Console.WriteLine("Downloading data ...");
                using (var wrtr = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, buffer.Length))
                {
                    var read=0;
                    while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
                    {
                        wrtr.Write(buffer,0,read);
                    }
                    wrtr.Flush();
                    wrtr.Close();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Data downloaded!");

                stream.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Response Failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with async on Stream reading and stream writing with no luck ...

this is my code sample using WebClient instead of HttpClient:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace StreamSpeedTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Sample video File
            const string fileUrl = "http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi";
            // SaveTo location
            const string file = "/tmp/big_buck_bunny.avi";

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start ...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            var finfo = new FileInfo(file);

            if (finfo.Directory == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong file path!");
                return;
            }

            if (!finfo.Directory.Exists) finfo.Directory.Create();

            Console.WriteLine("Downloading data ...");

            using (var client = new WebClient {Proxy = null})
            {
                client.DownloadFile(fileUrl, file);
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender,data)=> Console.WriteLine("Download File Completed!")
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: With WebClient.DownloadFile have same problem, CPU's run at 90-100%,  I have no preferences between HttpClient and WebClient, but with both have the same problem with cpu load.

Comment: This is weird. Please, show us your implementation with DownloadFile

Comment: Sorry, this is the implementation...

Comment: So the second implementation takes 100% of your CPU?

Comment: Yes...cpu load moves between 80-100% while download file....

Comment: Remove the last ReadKey()

Comment: The problem was not is the last ReadKey()...there was my fault, there was something weird when I test, after restart, the cpu usage is between 2% and 45%..I think is moore normal...by other side I thought the source of url was irrelevant, but not....I need do moore tests to clarify in which situation cpu grows up to 100%, thanks Thomas!